# Best practice for passing data from one component to another in angular

Tags: angular, angular-components

What is best practice for passing data from one component to another : Passing data using [value] = “value” or passing data using a service.

Comment: The answer is: it depends.

Comment: If you use NgRx then all the data is stored in the state, take a look, it worths a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular provides 3 different ways of parent-child interaction.

The suggested way for those interactions is via bindings (Input/Output). However, if the data does not belong to the parent component, a service is probably the better way. It is more clear and keeps the data hierarchy concise.

For components that are not close in the hierarchy, a service is probably the only way.